# how to find the index of an Object based array?

Tags: java, arrays

edit: why would you thumb down a genuine question from a completely new user? now I can only post every 3rd day. I thought this community was for helping each other, especially inexperienced people who are trying to learn. so dissapointing

given the following pseudo code:

```
public E findItem() {
    E temp;
    if (some condition...)
        temp = array[A];
    else 
        temp = array[B];

    return temp;


public E removeItem() {
    E itemToRemove = findItem();
}
```

how do I find the index of itemToRemove so that I can remove the value by expanding the removeItem method with array[foundIndex] = null;

the biggest problem I have is that all of the info I have been able to find within this subject covers arays that contain specific known types like int, String or Integer. in my situation, the type is not known until  the main method decides..

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right and have no conditions of complexity I would run over the array and search one by one for that object to remove, at the end return the index.

Another option is to give every object an ID based on some data which this specific object has and by that ID insert it to the array, then, when you try to remove it you will be using the data to calculate the ID and to remove by this ID, this want cost much in terms of complexity but you will have to find a way to calculate this ID.

Hope that I got you right